# does there exist a transcendental extension of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I think everyone know that $\mathbb{C}$ is an extension of $\mathbb{R}$.

Now I wondered if there exist an transcendental extension of $\mathbb{C}$

I know it's a short question but I can't find any extension, so I would say no, but can someone confirm that?

Comment: What about the polynomial ring $\mathbb C(x)$?

Comment: good comment... i didn't even think about it

Comment: by the way, $\mathbb C$ is an *algebraic*, not transcendental, extension of $\mathbb R$

Comment: Yes I thought so, so there still aren't any transcendental extensions of R

Comment: @mathmath $\mathbb R(x)$ is a transcendental extension of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: I mean of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: i made a mistake in my previous comment

Comment: @mathmath Aren’t you confusing algebraic and transcendental? What is true is that as $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed there is no proper algebraic extension of $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Yes i think so. After reading the answer from Tanner i think I confussed it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the field of rational functions $\mathbb C(x)$ is a transcendental extension of $\mathbb C$.

(Also, $\mathbb R(x)$ is a transcendental extension of $\mathbb R$,

whereas $\mathbb C$ is an algebraic extension of $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: You mean the field of rational functions. Except if you're talking about ring extensions, but then it should be $\mathbb C[x]$ instead of $\mathbb C(x)$.

Comment: Thank you, @Vercassivelaunos, for pointing out my mistake; I have edited to correct it